# Why is useEffect executing despite its dependency not being set?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can anyone explain why this useEffect is running before its dependency is set (and thus causing an error)? State is explicitly set as null initially, and the useEffect has state has its dependency, so surely it should only run once state has been set (to "something" in this case)?

```
const SomeComponent = () => {

    const [state, setState] = useState(null)

    async function someFunction() {
        ...
        setState("something")
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("State is: ",state)
    },[state])
}
```

Comment: In most cases logic in the `useEffect` needs to run after initialization too, so it is implemented that way, why don't you just add a null check?

Comment: useEffect hooks will run on the first render and when any of their dependencies change.

Comment: Thanks Linda, Nadia. I didn't realise useEffect runs on first render even if it has a dependency. Useful to know, but frustrating in equal measure

Comment: Like what @NadiaChibrikova said, add a `null` check inside of your `useEffect` if you don't want whatever is inside of it to run on initial render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UseEffect according to [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

> runs both after the first render and after every update.

This means if you remove the state from parameters, it will render only on the first render, which can be useful.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("This is first render")
},[])
```